# Add/Update/Merge original DataFrame into a grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**How can I merge, update, join, concat, or filter the original DF correctly so that I can have the complete 78 columns?**

I have a DataFrame with 22 rows and 78 columns. An internet-friendly version of the file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0w628bzi9gegr8/original_df.csv?dl=0). This a sample:

```
item_no     code            group   gross_weight    net_weight  value   ... ... +70 columns more
1           7417.85.24.25   0       18              17          13018.74
2           1414.19.00.62   1       35              33          0.11
3           7815.80.99.96   0       49              48          1.86
4           1414.19.00.62   1       30              27          2.7
5           5867.21.36.92   1       31              24          94
6           9227.71.84.12   1       24              17          56.4
7           1414.19.00.62   0       42              35          0.56
8           4465.58.84.31   0       50              42          0.94
9           1596.09.32.64   1       20              13          0.75
10          2194.64.27.41   1       38              33          1.13
11          1596.09.32.64   1       53              46          1.9
12          1596.09.32.64   1       18              15          10.44
13          1596.09.32.64   1       35              33          15.36
14          4835.09.81.44   1       55              47          10.44
15          5698.44.72.13   1       51              49          15.36
16          5698.44.72.13   1       49              45          2.15
17          5698.44.72.13   0       41              33          16
18          3815.79.80.69   1       25              21          4
19          3815.79.80.69   1       35              30          2.4
20          4853.40.53.94   1       53              46          3.12
21          4853.40.53.94   1       50              47          3.98
22          4853.40.53.94   1       16              13          6.53
```

The column group gives me the instruction that I should group all similar values in the code column and add the values in the columns: 'gross_weight', 'net_weight', 'value', and 'item_quantity'. Additionally, I have to modify 2 additional columns as shown below:

```
#Group DF
grouped_df = df.groupby(['group', 'code'], as_index=False).agg({'item_quantity':'sum', 'gross_weight':'sum','net_weight':'sum', 'value':'sum'}).copy()

#Total items should be equal to the length of the DF
grouped_df['total_items'] = len(grouped_df)

#Item No.
grouped_df['item_no'] = [x+1 for x in range(len(grouped_df))]
```

This is the result:

```
    group   code            item_quantity   gross_weight    net_weight  value       total_items     item_no
0   0       1414.19.00.62   75.0            42              35          0.56        14              1
1   0       4465.58.84.31   125.0           50              42          0.94        14              2
2   0       5698.44.72.13   200.0           41              33          16.0        14              3
3   0       7417.85.24.25   1940.2          18              17          13018.74    14              4
4   0       7815.80.99.96   200.0           49              48          1.86        14              5
5   1       1414.19.00.62   275.0           65              60          2.81        14              6
6   1       1596.09.32.64   515.0           126             107         28.45       14              7
7   1       2194.64.27.41   151.0           38              33          1.13        14              8
8   1       3815.79.80.69   400.0           60              51          6.4 18      14              9
9   1       4835.09.81.44   87.0            55              47          10.44       14              10
10  1       4853.40.53.94   406.0           119             106         13.63       14              11
11  1       5698.44.72.13   328.0           100             94          17.51       14              12
12  1       5867.21.36.92   1000.0          31              24          94.0        14              13
13  1       9227.71.84.12   600.0           24              17          56.4        14              14
```

All of the columns in the grouped DF exist in the original DF but some have different values.

**How can I merge, update, join, concat, or filter the original DF correctly so that I can have the complete 78 columns?**

- The objective DataFrame is the grouped DF.
- The columns in the original DF that already exists in the Grouped DF should be omitted.
- I should be able to take the first value of the columns in the original DF that aren't in the Grouped DF.
- The column code does not have unique values.
- The column part_number in the complete file does not have unique values.

I tried:

- pd.Merge(how='left') after creating a unique ID; it duplicates existing columns instead of updating values or overwriting.
- join, concat, update: does not yield the expected results.
- `.agg({lambda x: x.iloc[0]})` adds all the columns but I don't know how to add it to the current `.agg({'item_quantity':'sum', 'gross_weight':'sum','net_weight':'sum', 'value':'sum'})`
- I know that `.agg({'column_name':'first'])` returns the first value, but I don't know how to make it work for over 70 columns automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this dynamically creating a dictionary with list comprehension like this:

```
df.groupby(['group', 'code'], as_index=False).agg({col : 'sum' for col in df.columns[3:]}
```

If `item_no` is your index, then change `df.columns[3:]` to `df.columns[2:]`

Comment: Thank you! I am very close to my desired output. I am having trouble with my list comprehension  though:`grouped_df = df.groupby(['group', 'code'], as_index=False).agg({col:('sum' if col in columns_to_sum else 'list') for col in df.columns})` It gives me: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'list'. Do you have any idea how can I fix my statement? Columns_to_sum is a list of 4 column names where I need to sum the values, for the others, I just need the first value.